# bison how to call pointer declared in %union

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

Here is a little part of my code, and I got an error saying

> request for member 's' is something not a structure or a union.

I have this error because I don't need anymore to use s, because I specified his type. The problem I have, is that I need another way to make refference to that 's', instead of $3.s , and I can't find how to do that. If I put only $3, I won't get an error at '$3.s[0]', but I'll get an error at 'strcpy($3.s, $3.s+1)'
I am new in lex&yacc and the things that I know until now, can't help me to solve this.

```
%union{
            int i;
            char *s;
    }

%left '+','-'
%left '*','/'
%left UNARYMINUS
%type <i> expr
%type <s> instr
%token <i> NUMBER
%token <s> WORD
%token <s> SPACE

%%

instr:  SPACE instr        {          }
       |WORD '=' expr ';' { 
                              int v;
                              if ($3.s[0]=='$')
                              {
                                fprintf(fout, "\tmove\t$%d, %s\n\n", variabile($1.s), $3.s);
                                strcpy($3.s, $3.s+1);
                                v=atoi($3.s);
                                if (v>nvar)
                                  erasereg(v);
                              }
                              else
                                fprintf(fout, "\taddi\t$%d, $0, %s\n\n", variabila($1.s), $3.s);
                              free($1.s);
                              free($3.s);
                            }
       ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `%type <i> expr`, you tell Yacc that `expr` is an integer but you still check whether it points to `$`. It's either one or the other. Instead of trying to cram all the functionality into the block that parses `instr`, you could:

- match `$variables` with lex rules and look it up in the symbol table there

  ```
  "$"[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* { return var_lookup(yytext); }
  ```
- Or you could look them up in the yacc rule for `expr`

  ```
  expr: WORD {
        $$ = $1[0]=='$' ? var_lookup($1) : atoi($1);
  }
  ```

Also,  Arguments to `%left` are separated by spaces, not commas, and you don't call non-function pointers, you use/dereference them.